# Icinga Performance issue when using many service groups

Tags: monitoring, nagios, icinga

We have an Icinga installation with more than 3k active service checks. Performance is acceptable. We're already using the [use_large_installation_tweaks](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/configmain.html#configmain-use_large_installation_tweaks) option.

We have now started to build a sophisticated hierachy of service groups. Service groups are stacked into one another using the [servicegroup_members](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/objectdefinitions.html#servicegroup) configuration option.

Once we import the additional service groups performance massively degrades. Any HTTP request to the classic UI starts taking multiple seconds. During this time, a single thread causes a lot of CPU load.

We would like to rectify this isssue in order to be able to use the service group hierachy as planned.

Any ideas what causes this load and how to speed up Icinga in this regard?

We're using Icinga 1.11.1